# How to pass/append url parameter to all hrefs (links) on a page?

Tags: javascript

Using javascript, my objective is to query the URL and append parameters to all links on a page. If the link already contains a parameter, the link will append the new parameters:

> User access page:https://example.com/?location=brazil 
> Link on page was: https://link.com/?hello=ok 
> Link becomes: https://link.com/?hello=ok&location=brazil

If there's no previous parameter on link, it becomes: 
https://link.com/?location=brazil

I tried the following code:

```
var queryString = new URL(window.location).search;
document.querySelectorAll("[href]").forEach(link => {
    var current = link.href;
    link.href = current + queryString;
});
</script>
```

But when a link already contains a parameter, it uses **?** instead of **&**
so it becomes:

https://link.com/?hello=ok?location=brazil

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var queryString = new URL(window.location).search;
document.querySelectorAll("[href]").forEach(link => {
    var current = link.href;
    link.href = `${current}${current.includes('?') ? queryString.replace('?', '&') : queryString}`;
});
```

Comment: It worked beautifully! Thank you Sasuke.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if the queryString variable contains a `?` and replace it with a `&` instead.

So your code would be something like

```
var queryString = new URL(window.location).search;
document.querySelectorAll("[href]").forEach(link => {
    var current = link.href;
    const queryStrToUse = queryString.replace('?', '&')
    link.href = current + queryStrToUse;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to change the anchor href attribute with javascript for many reasons, but if this is a must you can do:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(link => {
link.href = link.href.includes("?") ? link.href + queryString.replace("?", "&") : link.href + queryString; });
```

Comment: Stefan, do you mind explaining if there's a better way to achieve this? Instead of using javascript.

Comment: It is a very bad practice for a public website, if you do not care about SEO, you can do it. One anchor generated at server must remain as is otherwise.